# Does Github upload the whole file?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I released a asp.net application's source code to Github by packing all it's source code to a zip file because for some reason I couldn't do it the normal way.

Now i changed a few files inside that archive (which is quiet large) and i commited changes and expected a large file upload but Github GUI did it all in few seconds.

Now my question is does git upload the whole zip file or what? how is this possible to only upload parts of an archive and yet achieve the same result as uploading it all??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not upload whole files, it uploads changes to files only. If you change part of a file, only the space required to show that change will be used.